# How to implement the new invisible reCAPTCHA on form?

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to get the new "invisible" version of the google reCAPTCHA working on my form.

I am using the https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha

According to the docs, you should just be able to do change this in the config.yml and I assume it would be invisible?

```
default_size: "invisible"
```

--

```
public function HelloForm() {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            new TextField('Name'),
            new EmailField('Email'),
            new TextareaField('Message')
        );
        $actions = new FieldList(
            new FormAction('doSubmitHelloForm', 'Submit')
        );

        $form = new Form($this, 'HelloForm', $fields, $actions);

        $form->enableSpamProtection()
            ->fields()->fieldByName('Captcha')
            ->setTitle("Spam protection")
            ->setDescription("Please tick the box to prove you're a human and help us stop spam.");

        return $form;
    }
```

**config.yml**

```
NocaptchaField:
  site_key: "MYKEYINHERE" #Your site key (required)
  secret_key: "MYKEYINHERE" #Your secret key (required)
  verify_ssl: true #Allows you to disable php-curl's SSL peer verification by setting this to false (optional, defaults to true)
  default_theme: "light" #Default theme color (optional, light or dark, defaults to light)
  default_type: "image" #Default captcha type (optional, image or audio, defaults to image)
  default_size: "invisible" #Default size (optional, normal, compact or invisible, defaults to normal)
  proxy_server: "" #Your proxy server address (optional)
  proxy_auth: "" #Your proxy server authentication information (optional)
```

However the captcha is still showing, am I missing something? (Please note I am just testing this on my local dev machine atm).

[image]

Comment: Did you flush after changing the configuration?

Comment: @RobbieAverill - Yep sure did.

Comment: I don't believe any reCaptcha module around currently supports the (brand new!) invisible one. I would, however, suggest to switch to the chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha module, as it seems slightly better maintained and is owned by SilverStripe's own Chillu.

Comment: @SimonErkelens [the readme](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha/commit/89fa4a8cf39d38c49c3d6ce402473227f98e2807) for the module in the question seems to suggest it does support "invisible" size

Comment: I have created an issue ticket on the module. So will see what the author says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there were 2 issues here.

1. I was using an older version of the nocaptcha module initially. I then upgraded to 0.3.0 (Latest release at the time of posting this) and the captcha was hidden as we wanted.
2. There was a bug in the module that meant it kept showing an error message when form was submitted (Saying the captcha needed to be ticked). The author has now fixed this and will be tagging this release soon as 0.4.0.

:)